# Illustrator: how to export multiple logos from SVG to PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, image-quality, resize

I am working with a bunch of SVG logos each placed in a 200x200 pixel artboard. When exporting these to PNG, they turn out to be pixelated. What is the fastest and best way to export them as high quality logos without having to go through the hassle of scaling the artboards and logos individually?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting various icons at the same size from Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84348/exporting-various-icons-at-the-same-size-from-illustrator)

Answer (score 5):

PNG is a bitmap image format and 200 pixels square is pretty tiny so visible pixelation is inevitable. Assuming that the logos exist in a vector format, the solution would be to export them at a higher resolution or as a vector file.

It's impossible to offer more specific advice without knowing the intended use case.

Comment: Hello Christ, thank you for advice. I am intending to use it on a webpage(uploading them to wordpress). I am not sure if wordpress is able to read vector format. Is there any recommendation on exporting?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Asset Exporter panel to generate various scales and formats of your artboards instantly. Menu > Window > Asset Export

Comment: Hello Silly-V thank you for your advice. I am using a Mac though, I will try searching up online on where is asset export for Mac.

Comment: It is only available in some of the latest Adobe Illustrator CC versions though. Well, it looks like you're up to date - so go to the menu bar all the way at the top and find the menu item "Window" and go down till you find "Asset Export".

Answer (score 1):

I read above that you are planning to use these images for a wordpress site. If so, just install the wordpress plugin entitled [SVG Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/)